# Got Error Module 'CommonLib' not found

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

When i run the BrowserFieldDemo on Simulator which is provided in the Blackberry Samples.
I am getting the **error Module 'CommonLib' not found.**
Before Running the Application i also configure MDS simulator but getting the above error can anyone please tell me why i getting this error.
I am using Blackberry jde 5,simulator:- 9550 and blackberry eclipse plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean simulator. It is under Blackberry menu in Eclipse. Or clean .dmp files manually.

Comment: I cant see clean.dmp file there is one batch file name clean.bat and run it now working like charm..... Thanks redline

Comment: C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\simulator this is the path of the Clean.bat file in my case ......

Comment: Can you tell me why this happen if we dont clean simulator what is the reason behind that ....

Comment: No no, not clean.dmp... I meant that there are some files which have extention of .dmp in simulator folder. You can delete these files manually.

Comment: no its working fine by running that clean.bat file but i want to know why this happens previously i had an application which also implementing Browserfield When i ran that application it was working fine and when i ran This Demo application it was giving me Error ....

Answer (score 0):

First check your workspace, Is there any project with name "CommonLib".If not then Just import "CommonLib" from Blackberry Sample.

I think it solve your problem.